# Command in minecraft 1.9 doesnt work but it should

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a little problem and I cant figure out why. I am trying to execute an image of block 16*16 to position few block away (about 20) and I use command `/execute @e[name=Horizontal] ~ ~ ~ clone ~ ~1 ~1 ~ ~8 ~8  4 84 37` The command works if I type it as a player, but if I want to put it in the command block and power it, the result is

> [17:58:26] Failed to execute 'clone ~ ~1 ~1 ~ ~8 ~8  4 84 37' as Horizontal

Could you please tell me why is this happening? Thanks (I am using minecraft snapshot 15w49b)

Comment: When you run it yourself, do you do so at the same physical location as "Horizontal"? If not, do so and you should receive the actual error.

Comment: i run the same command /execute @e[name=Horizontal] ~ ~ ~ clone ~ ~1 ~1 ~ ~8 ~8  4 84 37 and it works with message 64 block cloned

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have extra space between **~8** and **4**
also, make sure that areas don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

There are no problems with the command, so I would suggest double-checking your entity and making sure that it's name is spelled correctly, case sensitive.